# Automatically compute `maxExtent` of `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-sliver

Consider the following example that is intended to render a pinned title bar (with a potentially custom long/short text) inside of a `CustomScrollView`.

```dart
class TitleBar extends StatelessWidget {
  TitleBar(this.text);

  final String text;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) => Text(
        text,
        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30),
        maxLines: 3,
        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
      );
}

class TitleBarDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final String text;

  TitleBarDelegate(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent) => TitleBar(text);

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(TitleBarDelegate oldDelegate) => oldDelegate.text != text;

  @override
  double get maxExtent => ???;

  @override
  double get minExtent => maxExtent; // doesn't shrink
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: Scaffold(
        body: CustomScrollView(
          slivers: [
            SliverPersistentHeader(
              pinned: true,
              delegate: TitleBarDelegate('Potentially very long text'),
            ),
            SliverToBoxAdapter(
              child: Text("Foo " * 1000),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

The question is: How can I compute `maxExtent` based on the actual `TitleBar`. The problem is that the actual `TitleBar`'s size depends on the text and is hence to generally computable in advance.

Note that `TitleBar` might also have some more complex layout than it has in the example above. So the general question is how to 'shrink-wrap' an `SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate`.

Answer (score 2):

This is another dirty/hacky solution since it will involve building the thing twice.

The height of a widget can only be retrieved after building it, so the idea is to get its height post-build via its `GlobalKey` and rebuild the widget again, wrapped within `SliverPersistentHeader` with its height set as the `maxExtent`. The rebuilding is invoked by `ValueListenableBuilder` and its listener.

For this example below, I wish to set the calculated height as the `minExtent` and `maxExtent`

```dart
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/scheduler.dart';

class DynamicHeightSliverPinningHeader extends StatefulWidget {
  final Widget widget;

  const DynamicHeightSliverPinningHeader({
    super.key,
    required this.widget,
  });

  @override
  State<DynamicHeightSliverPinningHeader> createState() => _DynamicHeightSliverPinningHeaderState();
}

class _DynamicHeightSliverPinningHeaderState extends State<DynamicHeightSliverPinningHeader> {
  final _widgetKey = GlobalKey<_DynamicHeightSliverPinningHeaderState>();
  final _widgetHeightNotifier = ValueNotifier<double>(-1);

  late Widget _widget;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _widget = Container(
      key: _widgetKey,
      child: widget.widget,
    );

    SchedulerBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      // This would've been done after the first frame is built
      // This should invoke the ValueListenableBuilder to rebuild 
      _widgetHeightNotifier.value = _widgetKey.currentContext!.size!.height;
    });

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ValueListenableBuilder(
      valueListenable: _widgetHeightNotifier,
      builder: (context, _, __) {
        
        // This should be returned from the start.
        if (_widgetHeightNotifier.value == -1) {
          return SliverToBoxAdapter(
            child: _widget,
          );
        }
        
        // This should be returned after the listener detects the change.
        return SliverPersistentHeader(
          pinned: true,
          delegate: SliverPinningHeaderDelegate(
            _widget,
            _widgetHeightNotifier.value,
            _widgetHeightNotifier.value,
          ),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}

class SliverPinningHeaderDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {
  final Widget widget;

  @override
  final double minExtent, maxExtent;

  const SliverPinningHeaderDelegate(
    this.widget,
    this.maxExtent,
    this.minExtent,
  );

  @override
  Widget build(
    BuildContext context,
    double shrinkOffset,
    bool overlapsContent,
  ) {
    return widget;
  }

  @override
  bool shouldRebuild(covariant SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate oldDelegate) => true;
}
```

To detail out the rendering behaviour by a bit:

- it first renders the widget itself in `SliverToBoxAdapter` (bound with a `GlobalKey`)
- after the first frame is rendered, it gets calculated height from said `GlobalKey` and assign that value to the `ValueNotifier`
- with that, the `ValueNotifier` change is listened, and with said height, the `ValueListenableBuilder` will rebuild the widget that is wrapped within `SliverPersistentHeader` and its delegate

Answer (score 1):

I recently faced the same issue and came up with the following "dirty" solution, assuming the header only contains text with a given text style and you provide it with a max width value.

The **SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate** looks like this:

```
class SliverPersistentTitleDelegate extends SliverPersistentHeaderDelegate {

SliverPersistentTitleDelegate({
    @required this.width,
    @required this.text,
    this.textStyle,
    this.padding,
    this.extend = 10
}) {
    // create a text painter
    final TextPainter textPainter = TextPainter(
        textDirection: TextDirection.ltr,
    )
    ..text = TextSpan(
        text: text,
        style: _textStyle,
    );

    // layout the text with the provided width, taking the horizontal padding into account
    final double horizontalPadding = _padding.left + _padding.right;
    textPainter.layout(maxWidth: width - horizontalPadding);

    // measure minHeight and maxHeight, taking the vertical padding and text height into account
    final double verticalPadding = _padding.top + _padding.bottom;
    _minHeight = textPainter.height + verticalPadding;
    _maxHeight = minHeight + extend;
}

final double width;
final String text;
final TextStyle textStyle;
final EdgeInsets padding;
final double extend;
double _minHeight;
double _maxHeight;

final core.ThemeProvider _themeProvider = di.get<core.ThemeProvider>();

@override
double get minExtent => _minHeight;

@override
double get maxExtent => maxHeight;

TextStyle get _textStyle => this.textStyle
    ?? _themeProvider
        .defaultTheme
        .appBarTheme
        .textTheme;

EdgeInsets get _padding => padding ?? EdgeInsets.zero;

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context, double shrinkOffset, bool overlapsContent)
{
    return Padding(
        padding: _padding,
        child: Text(
            text,
            style: _textStyle ,
        ),
    );
}

@override
bool shouldRebuild(SliverPersistentTitleDelegate oldDelegate) {

    return width != oldDelegate.width
        || text != oldDelegate.text
        || textStyle != oldDelegate.textStyle
        || padding != oldDelegate.padding
        || extend != oldDelegate.extend
        || _maxHeight != oldDelegate._maxHeight
        || _minHeight != oldDelegate._minHeight;
}
```

}

Using this class is simple:

```
return LayoutBuilder(
    builder: (context, constrains) {

    return CustomScrollView(
        slivers: <Widget>[
            SliverPersistentHeader(
                pinned: false,
                floating: true,
                delegate: SliverPersistentTitleDelegate(
                    width: constrains.maxWidth,
                    text: "Some long dynamic title",
                    textStyle: titleTextStyle,
                    padding: EdgeInsets.only(
                        left: 16,
                        right: 16,
                    ),
                ),
            )
        ],
    );
},
```

);

Answer (score -1):

I think you may be looking for `_titleBar.preferredSize.height` but I can't be sure